# Extract bathymetry data from a map

Tags: image-processing, geography

Thanks everybody for edit and recommend. Here is a clearer version of my question.

I have a map that shows bathymetry of a lake with legend showing depth relative to a range of color. The map projection is WGS84 UTM Zone 48 North and co-ordinates is available in the map:

[image: bathymetry map]

I evaluated

```
img=Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4pXK.png"];
PixelValuePositions[img, {1, 0.149, 0}]
```

to get a list of pixel positions have the same R G B value (color red) in this map  `img`. However, these pixel positions are determined by row and column not the map co-ordinates.
My question is: How to make *Mathematica* converting these pixel positions to UTM coordinates? So that I can extract bathymetry data from this map.

Comment: "If this image is a map that is geo-referenced" <-- What does "geo-referenced" mean?  Do some images contain metadata that could be used to align them with a map?  (I have no experience with this.)

Comment: I don't see why you can't do it manually: e.g., if the map's image represents an equirectangular projection, just `Rescale[]` the image coordinate system `{{0, w}, {0, h}}` to `{{-180, 180}, {-90, 90}}`.

Comment: It would greatly help if you could provide the image. How is it obtained? What kind of projection is it?

Comment: Now, any answer to this question will have to remove the legend first… :) more seriously, is this supposed to be an equirectangular projection of the WGS84 ellipsoid?

Comment: @J.M. Please don't mind the legend. I just need to see how it works. I am not entirely understand these terms, but could you please give me a more detail your code how to `Rescale[]` the coordinate system? May be this is the solution I am looking for. I am very new in *Mathematica*.

Comment: Well, to be able to translate coordinates into actual longitudes/latitudes, you'll need to specify the map projection used. So, please answer the question in my previous comment.

Comment: oh, sorry, the map projection used is WGS84 UTM Zone 48 North.

Comment: @backorion. This is a great question and I was looking for the same answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I take a screenshot of your image and assign it to the image variable.

```
In[2]:= ImageDimensions[image]
Out[2]= {1326, 1150}
```

This computes the positions of the lines in your image:

```
In[3]:= lines = ImageLines[Binarize[ColorDistance[image, Gray], {0, .4}]]
Out[3]= {{{0., 638.044}, {1326., 638.044}}, {{0., 132.694}, {1326., 132.694}}, {{0., 891.219}, {1326., 891.219}}, {{0., 385.869}, {1326., 385.869}}, {{306.216, 1150.}, {305.29, 0.}}, {{810.64, 1150.}, {811.565, 0.}}, {{1063.74, 1150.}, {1062.81, 0.}}, {{558.465, 1150.}, {559.391, 0.}}}
```

Now I compute an approximate linear relation between the UTM x coordinate and the xpixel number:

```
In[4]:= Transpose[{Sort[Mean /@ lines[[{5, 6, 7, 8}, {1, 2}, 1]]], {584000, 585000, 586000,587000}}]
Out[4]= {{305.753, 584000}, {558.928, 585000}, {811.102, 586000}, {1063.28, 587000}}

In[5]:= x[xpixel_] = Fit[%, {1, xpixel}, xpixel]
Out[5]= 582788. + 3.96079 xpixel
```

Same thing for the y axis:

```
In[6]:= Transpose[{Sort[Mean /@ lines[[{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2}, 2]]], {2327000, 2328000, 2329000, 2330000}}]
Out[6]= {{132.694, 2327000}, {385.869, 2328000}, {638.044, 2329000}, {891.219, 2330000}}

In[7]:= y[ypixel_] = Fit[%, {1, ypixel}, ypixel]
Out[7]= 2.32647*10^6 + 3.95609 ypixel
```

Now we can compute the latlon coordinates of the bounding box of your image, using the information provided about projection and datum:

```
In[8]:= boundingbox = {GeoPosition[GeoGridPosition[{x[0], y[0]}, "UTMZone48", "WGS84"]],GeoPosition[GeoGridPosition[{x[1326], y[1150]}, "UTMZone48", "WGS84"]]}
Out[8]= {GeoPosition[{21.0372, 105.797}, "WGS84"], GeoPosition[{21.0781, 105.848}, "WGS84"]}
```

This is the corresponding GeoGraphics call:

```
In[9]:= GeoGraphics[GeoRange -> boundingbox, GeoProjection -> "UTMZone48"]
```

[image]

Finally, let me superpose your image on the map:

```
In[10]:= GeoGraphics[{GeoStyling[{"GeoImage", image}, Opacity[0.5]],  GeoBoundsRegion[boundingbox]}, GeoRange -> boundingbox, GeoProjection -> "UTMZone48"]
```

[image]

Comment: This is a +10 if I could give it. One question, how would you code this if the image did not have lines?

Comment: Thank you @jose. I've checked and it  works for Mathematica 10. However,  Mathematica 9 does not have "ColorDistance"

Comment: Bob, we need some reference points in the maps to establish a relation between the pixel coordinates and the actual map coordinates (either latlon or some projected coordinates). If there is nothing in the map that can be extracted programmatically with image or graphics tools, then one can always select points manually, for example using the coordinate tools (click on the image or GeoGraphics result and then press the period key). The 8th Application example in the GeoGraphics refpage (about manipulation of an image of Paris) can also give you ideas on how to place an image on a map.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that there is a linear relation between rows & columns and the UTM coordinates, one could do the following:

Find the rows and columns of the coordinate lines via marginal distributions:

```
{dimX,dimY} = ImageDimensions[img];

distX = Total[ImageData[ColorConvert[img, "Grayscale"]]]/dimY;

distY = Total[ImageData[ColorConvert[img, "Grayscale"]], {2}]/dimX;

peaksX = FindPeaks[1 - distX, 0, 0.5][[All, 1]];

peaksY = FindPeaks[1 - distY, 0, 0.5][[All, 1]];
```

Fit linear functions to map rows and columns into corresponding peak positions:

```
funcX = Evaluate[Fit[Transpose[{peaksX, ticksX}], {1, #}, #]] &;

funcY = Evaluate[Fit[Transpose[{peaksY, ticksY}], {1, #}, #]] &;
```

Finally, apply the two transformations on the row and column coordinates:

```
Apply[{funcX[#1], funcY[#2]} &, 
 PixelValuePositions[img, {1, 0.149, 0}], {1}]
```

Comment: @Markus van Almsick: could you pls explain a little bit more the line: "funcX = Evaluate[Fit[Transpose[{peaksX, ticksX}], {1, #}, #]] &;" ?What is "ticksX" and "ticksY"?  It was not declared before.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to note the list of tick values taken from the image:

Comment: ticksX = {584000, 585000, 586000, 587000};
ticksY = {2327000, 2328000, 2329000, 2330000};